# How to umount a file system being in kernel code

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am in kernel code and trying to umount a filesytem, before going to unload the driver.
Before that I want to umount the filesystem.

system(umount -t .....) does not work here.

Can any one please tell me how to umount in kerenel mode.

Comment: how about this: umount("...", 0); my guess is it won't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking source code of `umount()` system call at [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.6.6/fs/namespace.c#L1245) you can find out how unmount is done in kernel, here are some internals you may find useful:

```
real_mount()
check_mnt()
do_umount()
mntput_no_expire()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at how the *autofs* subsystem, i.e. the kernel automounter does it.